# URL encode using html forms

Tags: php, html, url, character-encoding

How to encode URLs containing Unicode? I would like to pass it to a command line utility and I need to encode it first.

```
<form action="index.php" method="get" >
<input type="text" name="find" value="عربي" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="search" />
<form />
```

Example:
http://localhost/index.php?find=عربي

becomes  http://localhost/index.php?find=%DA%D1%C8%ED

Comment: http://www.drupalcode.com/api/function/mb_urlencode/contrib-5.x-1.x

Comment: So you want to `عربي` as a parameter value but don’t know how to convert it into `%DA%D1%C8%ED`, right?

Comment: Why do you not use POST? POST request will encode properly.

Comment: @e-zinc So you want to tell anyone who doesn't use a language fully described by the ASCII charset that they just shouldn't use GET?

Comment: @rdlowrey I want only say that the POST usage will be easier if POST is allowed by server side.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat testme
#!/usr/local/bin/php
<?php

$chars = array( "d8", "b9", "d8", "b1", "d8", "a8", "d9", "8a" );

foreach ($chars as $one) {
    $string .= sprintf("%c", hexdec($one));
}

print "String: " . $string . "\n";
print "Encoded: " . urlencode($string) . "\n";

?>
$ ./testme
String: عربي
Encoded: %D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%8A
$
```

Answer (score 1):

`%DA%D1%C8%ED` is not Unicode sequence, but URL encoded sequence in other encoding.
`عربي` in Unicode after URL encoding should became `%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%8A`

If you want to construct valid URL with Unicode characters you can use something like:

```
$url = 'http://localhost/index.php?find=عربي';

$url_parts = parse_url($url);
$query_parts = array();
parse_str($url_parts['query'], $query_parts);
$query = http_build_query(array_map('rawurlencode', $query_parts));

$url_parts['query'] = $query;
$encoded_url = http_build_url($url_parts);
```

Note: This will only encode `query` part of URL.